# Indestructible silk: good armor?

Tags: physics, materials, armors, clothing

I've been playing with different conceptualizations and types of armor for historical settings, especially armor with magic enchantments or made from weird materials. I was stuck thinking about lightweight protection and remembered that mithril shirt from the Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Rings.

To those who haven't seen or read it, the mithril shirt is described as being stronger than steel but as supple as linen. This latter property confused me when the wearer got stabbed with the force of a battering ram, since the shirt would be fine, but the person wearing it should be suffering massive blunt force trauma and internal bleeding. Heck, with that degree of flexibility, you could even justify the shirt being forced inside the person wearing it.

With that in mind, would a silk shirt or coat that is (for all intents and purposes) indestructible, be useful as martial protection, or would it just be over-designed pajamas? For the purposes of this thought experiment, imagine the wearer of this shirt being struck by an arrow, a knife, a spear, and an ax.

Comment: If you're talking about the fight in Moria, Frodo was apparently hit so hard that the others thought he'd been killed, and some of the rings were driven through a leather shirt into his shoulder.  I also don't remember it being described as particularly supple.  It was very light (as well as extremely strong).  The lightness is not an advantage when being hit, but makes it possible for a hobbit to go on a quest while being very heavily armored.

Comment: Perhaps explain the definition of "flexible". Some answers assume it means "elastic" as well as flexible. I also assume that it is as light as silk, but in effect a metallic material similar to the Mythril from LOTR?

Comment: If you think about it, if all you wore was said silk, you'd still get a hole from a knife, it just wouldn't be as precise or as deep.  The flexibility of the cloth would wrap around the knife and happily puncture the body.  However, this stuff would make great hot air balloon material.  And great gloves.

Comment: "Indestructible" as in "absolutely impenetrable, after all the needle work is done and the enchantments are made"? Sure, just wear it instead of a chain mail, on top of that thick padding you wear under the chain mail.

Comment: I always figured that the mithril behaved like a non-newtonian fluid: supple when handled with light touches and slow motions, hard as kevlar when exposed to sudden and/or hard stabs.

Comment: You need an inertial damper. Such armor should have the ability to nullify all force above a certain threshold. The mechanism is similar to that of car belts. That way, you will be able to move inside it, but you won't get hammered by force.

Comment: A better use for the material might be to make a big and strong, yet lightweight and translucent _shield_ with it. That would give near perfect protection agains arrows, without limiting mobility much.

Comment: The answers to this question, https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/45590/would-armour-made-of-spider-silk-work?rq=1 , might be helpful.

Comment: @glaux I think you'd need to achieve that by the way the links mesh, rather than their material — but I'm off topic

Comment: Actually, forget the padding. Wear a "cage" made of rods, use it as an "embroidery frame" for the silk, e. g. stretch it tight over the frame. The frame would resist crushing and keep the silk several cm away from the body. The silk would resist pretty much anything else. The cage would be lighter and much easier to craft than solid plate armor.

Comment: If you rename your "indestructible silk" to Kevlar (R), and look into its uses, e.g. for puncture protection in tyres, slashguard(R) gloves and bullet-proof vests and helmets, you might get a good answer to your question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Silk armor was used for this purpose by [several real historical armies.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_armour) It's not going to STOP the blow the way I think you're imagining, but it does a few very useful things. It cushions the blow quite a bit, and against piercing weapons the silk will bind up around the point. So, to your point, it DOES get forced into the person wearing it, but that's actually one of the key benefits.

In the case of arrows it makes them much easier to remove without causing further damage, AND by keeping a layer of material that [has its own antibacterial properties](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23784754) between your innards and whatever you got stabbed with, it dramatically reduces the chances of infection.

So, if you want armor that will completely protect the wearer from getting slashed or stabbed, silk isn't going to do that. You need something very rigid and strong like plate armor for that.

BUT, if you want very lightweight, comfortable armor that doesn't slow you down, and makes it much more likely that you're going to SURVIVE being slashed or stabbed, silk will do that all day long and twice on Thors-day.

EDIT: I feel like I need to address a misconception I'm seeing in a number of responses, and emphasize the counterargument others have raised. If your indestructible silk has the same flexibility as real silk does, and you're wearing it loose, it **will not prevent sharp force trauma**. I have personal experience with this. It was denim in my case, not silk, but a sharp steel edge opened up a gash four inches across in my leg all the way down to the bone without actually cutting through the denim. You'd need to have padding underneath to prevent the silk from just forming an edge around the blade. Otherwise you still get wounded, it's just a very **clean** wound.

EDIT the Second: I didn't REALLY address indestructible silk versus the normal kind very well, so I'll elaborate a bit. Assuming that indestructible silk (like mithril) is rare and expensive, and if you have some you want to use it as effectively as possible, there are a couple ways you'd do it.

If you're a wealthy urban noble and you're worried about assassins and duels, then you can use it all by itself under more normal clothing, with all the pros and cons I noted above. You would ESPECIALLY want to make sure you've got matching GLOVES, because being able to protect your hands and arms from getting sliced during a rapier duel or knife fight is a HUGE advantage. The general wisdom in knife fighting is just accept that your arms and hands are going to get cut all to hell, and to keep your opponent from hitting anything vital until you can beat him, and hope you don't die of blood loss first. Rapiers are sharp, but don't have a lot of mass behind them so against a weapon like that, the silk will often cause what would be a deep stab into a glancing poke.

Now, if we're thinking about battlefield armor where you're expecting to get hit, and hit HARD, all day long, then you'd want the silk to be part of a gambeson or suchlike, with the silk layered over nice thick padding everywhere except the joints. If it were me, I might want a tough layer of leather over the top of that in certain places for things like fire, because silk doesn't really prevent heat transfer all that well.

All that would only slow you down about as much as a really heavy wool coat would (I used to have a Surplus Swedish Army Greatcoat I was very fond of), but would allow you to at least survive just about any human-scale armed strike I can think of, and would shrug off entirely anything that wasn't a direct hit.

Comment: I was looking for an answer to provide the actual historical use of silk armor, and it was even used in bullet resistant vests for a while, but you seem to have forgotten part of OP's premise in your second to last paragraph. This was compared to magic armor or to mithril armor, and it was described as indestructible silk. So slashes are what you _want_ your enemy to do. Slash all day long, all you're going to do is bruise the wearer. It is not going to cut in this fictitious case.

Comment: Also I noticed that you were one of few (only?) people who specifically responded to OP's point about getting the silk dragged into you. Agree that did happen, and in later bullet-proof vests it was also useful for getting the bullet out if it didn't rip through. You might want to draw more attention to that part of your answer.

Comment: @Aaron you'd think so, but no. A sharp edge can cut through skin and muscle without cutting through the fabric on top. I have vivid personal experience with this phenomena. I edited my post to include the details, but a loose silk shirt, even if indestructible, wouldn't necessarily keep you from getting cut or stabbed. It would just keep the wound really, really clean.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I do recall some wounds I've had before that happened through my clothing without ripping through. I will still suggest that slashing is what you want the opponent to do in this situation though, since it will be way less likely to cut you than normal, and it isn't as bad as say a mace or axe where the blunt force barely even cares that the silk is there. But yes, I agree with your experience now that you have reminded me of some of my own. Still, you already had my +1 before my first comment.

Comment: Wow, this explained the pros and cons to me very well, and I had no idea regrading antibacterial benefits. That's actually super helpful to me. Having this silk as a under-layer or over-layer with more rigid armor seems to be the best means of turning this into practical armor, even if it turned out more wound-reduction than damage prevention. Plus silk and steel is a fantastic visual pairing. Reinforcement for Gambasion is also an excellent idea. Thank you all for your sage advice-s and Morris, sorry to hear about the leg. That's one a heck of a citation.

Comment: @Pinion Minion It's cool, it was 35 years ago so nowadays It's just a good story. Glad I could help. Note that MOST of what I said doesn't even require 'indestructible' silk, Just the regular stuff will do. I added another edit to my answer to directly address what I think armor using 'indestructible' silk would be like.

Answer (score 13):

Its going to be extremely practical, with advantages and downsides compared to solid armors. Although it depends on how flexible exactly it is how good/bad it might be, less flexibility can help divide the forces across a larger bodily surface area. There are solutions for this.

Against arrows its going to be useful, it wont be pleasant getting hit but it'll not be lethal until you get hit by dozens to hundreds as you are slowly pummeled to death. Gives you time to get out of the way or have a few words with whoever is doing it, preferably with a sharp object.

Against knives it's useful. The opponent wont be able to cut you directly and it'll basically be a punch. However, if the material is too flexible the edge of the knife will still concentrate this punch force and make for a more dangerous punch. Ultra flexible and the material might just envelop the knife's edge and be almost as sharp as the knife, cutting you anyway indirectly!. Dont make it too flexible!

A spear is similar to a knife but on a stick and easier to put more force behind the jab.

An axe is similar to knife as well, but with more weight and a different trajectory behind it.

If you have access to this the weight and freedom of movement are its key advantages, and being able to wear this on a long march and still have energy to fight is going to be useful. Any flexibility issues can be solved by using leather armors beneath to spread (and cushion) the forces of a blow to your armor. Potentially even something like a thick layer of something light and cushioning, like wool, could work as well.

Edit because of popular comment: this fabrics most important purpose would be as a top layer over padded material. Getting stabbed or similar while only wearing a thin silken indestructible vest is still going to be worse than a normal punch. Similar to plate armors this wont do much against maces, flails and other blunt force objects where only more and more padding will provide protection.

Comment: On the flexibility issue - is it always flexible, or does it stiffen under high-impact, like [ookbleck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid#Oobleck)?

Comment: @Chronocidal that depends on the OP, I suspect that since he refers to the Mythril armor that there will be no non-newtonian fluids used and that it's always flexible.

Comment: Its worth emphasizing the last part. The application where this would really shine is over a layer of padding that would help spread the force from knives/swords/etc. Its worth noting that, even over reasonable padding, this would provide minimal protection from weapons like maces and warhammers that were never meant to penetrate the skin anyway.

Comment: To the metion of oobleck (and other non-Newtonian fluids) In John Ringo's "There Will Be Dragons" (Fantastic but extremely campy, like most John Ringo) there is futuristic chain link armor that is supple until it is struck. When it is struck, the links temporarily fuse together, acting like rigid plate.

Comment: What is your take on being hit by blunt objects? Even if the silk doesn't get cut by the axe, you're still being whacked by a heavy object. I don't think silk helps against being crushed.

Comment: @JAD I kind of mentioned it already: you are going to need some padding. Near the introduction of full-scale firearms plate armor got so good that cutting weapons stopped being very useful and things like maces and morning stars started being used. The indestructible linen would do little, but the leather and padding would.

Comment: -1 Armour works by distributing the force of the attack into a larger area that does not cause fatal damage to the person wearing it.  Any armour that flexible won't stop arrows, knives or axes, bullets or a punch, because it's not distributing the force anywhere.  You're basically wearing air armour, the most flexible armour around - and that doesn't work very well.  For the same reason, no amount of padding will help, because you may as well just be wearing the padding ....

Comment: @UKMonkey Armour's first and foremost attribute is preventing penetration of sharp objects like swords, knives, Spears and axes. Scimitars for example were build not for forcing the blade in but having as much of the cutting blade pass by the armor, cutting the leather and person. An indestructible linen "skin" would be incredibly useful. After that skin you have to think about distributing the force, such as a light leather armor instead of steel which was primarily used for how well the material resisted cutting.

Comment: @Demigan You're wrong.  Armours first and formost attribute is spreading the force to a larger area to reduce the pressure.  Remember that it is a high pressure that allows objects to cut.  The consequence of this is that penetrating weapons are unable to penetrate the person; and often (but not always) the armour.  If you can't reduce the pressure, like wearing a "flimsy but uncuttable cloth", then you can't stop it cutting.

Comment: @UKMonkey If you make an armor, do you use cotton that cushions or Kevlar that has the strength to prevent penetration? The INDESTRUCTIBLE linen provides all the strength to stop penetration, and then just needs something to cushion. A cutting edge does work by concentrating the force on a small a point as possible, but if the material cant stand up to the force before it spreads it out it's useless. Thats why we didnt stop at leather armors with padded vests beneath but went to metal: it has the material strength to hold up against a cutting force. It sucks against blunt forces though.

Comment: @Demigan At the risk of repeating myself - I use kevlar that has the strength to reduce the pressure without giving way.  The penetration of the bullet isn't important; because if it goes though with sufficiently low velocity it'll hurt but not kill.  The absolute stopping power isn't important; it's how much energy can be absorbed from the object and put in other areas.  ie - how can the pressure be reduced.  So no, I don't wear kevlar because it can prevent penetration, I wear it because the force of the bullet is spread to the size of a couple of inches which will just bruse me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82177/discussion-between-demigan-and-ukmonkey).

Comment: *"The opponent wont be able to cut you [...]"* This is not true. You will be cut by the silk instead of the knife. I think you meant "If you wear something rigid underneath the indestructible silk, then the opponent wont be able to cut you [...]". This is an option given later in the answer, so maybe a reorganization of the ideas in the answer would be a good idea.

Comment: @Rainbolt I do mean it. If the silk is a 1mm thick fabric for example and not elastic it'll form an edge thicker than that when you press the knife in, a bit hard to cut someone with a 1mm thick edge. If the fabric is thin but fits tightly around your body the fabric wont yield enough to form a new edge around the blade.

Comment: @Rainbolt this is absolutely right. I've got a six inch scar on my leg from a cut that went down to the bone that didn't do any visible damage at all to the pants I was wearing.

Comment: @Demigan I'm probably the one that is not communicating clearly, so let me try again. Third paragraph, second sentence says "The opponent wont be able to cut you". Same paragraph, fourth sentence says if the material is too flexible, the knife might cut you. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @Rainbolt ah I understand now, thanks. I'll edit it to "cannot cut your directly", will that solve the issue in combination with the later explanation of the fabric enveloping the knife?

Answer (score 10):

When we talk about bulletproof vests, we have to keep in mind that, compared to being pierced by a projectile, anything which gives less damage is to be preferred.

Bulletproof vests work by:

- spreading the impact on a larger surface, thus giving, for the same force, a lower pressure
- spreading the momentum over a longer time, which following the relationship $m \times \delta v = F \times \delta t$, results again in a lower force

But still the inflicted damage is non zero. Blunt traumas can be a consequence, broken ribs too.

So, to answer your question, yes, it would be useful to lower the damage consequent to an attack, but it won't completely avoid any damage.

Comment: Most cases where wearing a vest has saved someone's life have involved car accidents, not shootings.

Comment: Also most Vests DO have plates (ceramic or so) in them to distribute the impact energy

Comment: @ivanivan - wut?

Answer (score 8):

This actually might work in a very limited way, but it needs rigidity added.

You could have this silk armor as a base layer, then add a chest plate, shoulder pads, helmet, and braces and have competent armor as all your vitals are now protected.  All your laceration prone spots are protected by the silk.  Add leggings if horse combat is required.

The rest of your body is largely bone and muscle, and can take a blunt force hit fairly easily comparatively speaking. The trade off for speed and flexibility might be worth the extra vulnerability.

Comment: +1 for layering armor

Answer (score 4):

It could work but not by itself.

It needs to be over some kind of ridged structure to keep it stretched tight.

The reason it won't work by itself is that it will deform and allow kinetic energy to be transferred to the body behind it.

Yes, you won't get cut but that doesn't help you if the blow from the axe shoves the silk shirt through your sternum and heart.  The only good thing is that you can pull it out of the body, wash it off and then give it to someone else.

Also, silk is flammable. Does being indestructible stop that or does it leave the wearer in a burning shirt that they can't get off?

Answer (score 4):

If your 'indestructible' silk armour is as thin and flexible as pyjamas then its biggest flaw is as you've already noted: it does little to protect against blunt force trauma. It's still really useful and practical for keeping out the point ends of axes and arrows but it does nothing to stop the wearer from being clubbed to death.

This silk armour would be much more effective when worn over a gambeson or thick furs. They'd provide exactly what your super silk lacks, padding to cushion against blunt force. When paired I think the combination would prove superior to plate mail, as it'd provide as much protection(actually more since plate does little against a mace or warhammer) while being much lighter, inhibiting mobility a lot less and also insulating against cold.

TL;DR: Frodo should've worn a gambeson as well

Answer (score 2):

The reduction to blunt force damage will be related to the softness and thickness of the material. In the case of thin silk armor, probably not very much. This could be increased by wearing the armor loosely, making for a sort of air-barrier.

However, if the armor was tightly fitted to the person's skin, then the force required to pierce someone by forcing the silk into them will be the same as the force required to compress their entire body; it would be a significant help against arrows and knives.

Comment: I was just thinking that. Ideally, you want a sort of silk corset armor.

Answer (score 2):

## If it is truly indestructible, then YES!

If your silk is really indestructible, then a little bit of molten-metal forging will not bother it at all.

So make fiberglass armor out of it.
Except, don't use glass fibers, use the silk.
And don't use silly resin, use the hardest steel you can lay your hands on.
!!not the toughest, you want **hard**!!
If you have the means to forge diamond, that would be ideal.
The addition of utterly unbreakable strands in the hard material will render it as resistant to damage as mere physical material can get. To penetrate this composite armor, you would need to break each and every bond between the steel and the fibers, just to enable a local breakthrough. But your steel is saturated with millions of unbreakable strands.

**In effect, to penetrate a hard steel bound to unbreakable silk substrate, you would need to powder the steel finer than the gaps between the silk strands!!**

Impact aside, I can see a 1mm layer of this armor stopping a railgun projectile. The anti-Yamato-Battleship type railgun.

Funny things happen to material sciences and physics when one starts throwing around terms such as "infinite" and "completely indestructible"

footnotes:
For the silk to be truly indestructible, it must not stretch. At all.
It must not break, ever.
This means its Young's Modulus needs to be.. infinite.
This also mean that the speed of sound in the strands is.. infinite.
This means that any mechanical stress applied to an object comprised of these strands, is simultaneously and equally applied to every strand, ever position in the object, equally.
It does not matter if the impacting object is a pin of a bowling ball, the impact is distributed to the whole object, equally.

I have absolutely no clue how one would go about even bending a strand of the stuff, much less penetrating armor made out of it. You could cut a black hole in half with this stuff!

I think we should quantify "indestructible" with some numeric, non-infinite number. For the safety of all existence.

Answer (score 1):

Silk was generally worn the the undergarment for reasons noted above. It's worth noting though that Kevlar an carbon filament armour is usually part of a composite involving resin to provide stiffness.

Answer (score -1):

It would be perfect for armor, look at the medieval gambeson.

Granted the Gambeson was a reasonably bulky piece of clothing and wearing it was the equivalent of walking around in a heavy winter coat all day, so it might not be entirely what you are looking for in terms of armor, but it is the lightest effective armor known during medieval style period. It was the primary armor used across most cultures of the time as it was cheap and easy to create and repair.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambeson

It is made of many layers of quilted wool or linen cloth, approximately 18 to 30 layers and was great protection from most common threats a soldier would face on the battlefield.

The thickness of the fabric allowed it to act as padding against many blunt force trauma weapons, while not foolproof it did lessen the impact by a good deal, which is why it was often worn under maille, plate, and brigandine armors to pad against blunt force.

Against slashing blows the gambeson would have the upper layers cut, but unless a mighty blow was struck by a very impractically sharp sword it would not cut all the way through.

Against piercing weaponry such as arrows it isn't perfect defense as they would still penetrate through by pulling the weave apart, but if thick enough, could stop the occaisional arrow or dagger thrust.

Now if your Gambeson was made of indestructible silk the whole ballgame is changed, because now it  would be impervious to slashing cuts, there is no way a blade would be able to slice through no matter how sharp.

However that being said, against blunt trauma due to it's layered cushioned structure, it was a good cushion allowing for the wearer to shrug off most things short of a pretty hefty mace. If the fabric had enough layers, I'd wager it could turn a most likely fatal hit from a rifle into a big bruise.

Against piercing weaponry it would improve quite substantially, because anything short of a thin point designed to pierce this armor would be shrugged off like a slashing weapon, However this would lead to the development of needle-like arrows and blades that can poke between the fibers of the fabric, so it wouldn't be foolproof but way better than anything else available short of full plate armor.

So, in short, your silk armor could work very well, but only if properly layered.

Comment: The gambeson is addressed as part of the (more comprehensive) accepted answer.

Comment: @jdunlop I felt I could elaborate a bit on it as it was only briefly touched on.